# Inserting over 100,00 rows into ms-sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an sql script that has over 100,000 individual insert statements.  The sql is correct as I it will run if I choose small portions of the statements but it will not run if I run the entire script.  It throws an error but does not give a reason like it typically does.  I have opened the script in management studio to see if their may be something wrong with one of the statements but it all looks correct.  I have run scripts in the past and it will usually insert up to a point and then give me an error.  It will not even insert the first row, but if I select just that row and execute it inserts no issue.

Could their be a limit to the number of inserts allowed? Here is a small sample of the insert statements.  They are all basically the same just a lot more.

```
Insert into test (Article_ID, Product_ID, Name, Description, Type, Category, Color, Price, Commission, Currency, URL_Product, URL_Picture__big_ ) values ( 101661638, 1005344977, 'In Russ We Trust', 'Exclusive to Morel Tees - Show your support for one of the NBA''s "premier" point guards - Oklahoma City Thunder''s Russell Westbrook.  Design depicts the Oklahoma City skyline, the #0 and the faith that Oklahoma City Thunder fan''s have for their star point guard.  Limited Time Only Online Only', 'Men''s Premium T-Shirt', 'T-Shirts', 'royal blue', 25, 9.6, 'USD', 'http://MorelTees.spreadshirt.com/in-russ-we-trust-A101661638', 'http://image.spreadshirtmedia.com/image-server/v1/products/1005344977/views/1,width=190,height=190.png' );
Insert into test (Article_ID, Product_ID, Name, Description, Type, Category, Color, Price, Commission, Currency, URL_Product, URL_Picture__big_ ) values ( 16746212, 1001526574, 'Team Trash Talk - Crossover', 'Exclusive to Morel Tees - Team Trash Talk ankle breaking crossover. A must have for those that lack trash talk game.', 'Men''s T-Shirt', 'T-Shirts', 'white', 20, 2, 'USD', 'http://MorelTees.spreadshirt.com/team-trash-talk-crossover-A16746212', 'http://image.spreadshirtmedia.com/image-server/v1/products/1001526574/views/2,width=190,height=190.png' );
Insert into test (Article_ID, Product_ID, Name, Description, Type, Category, Color, Price, Commission, Currency, URL_Product, URL_Picture__big_ ) values ( 16746194, 1001526704, 'Team Trash Talk - Crossover', 'Exclusive to Morel Tees - Team Trash Talk ankle breaking crossover. A must have for those that lack trash talk game.', 'Men''s T-Shirt', 'T-Shirts', 'black', 20, 2, 'USD', 'http://MorelTees.spreadshirt.com/team-trash-talk-crossover-A16746194', 'http://image.spreadshirtmedia.com/image-server/v1/products/1001526704/views/2,width=190,height=190.png' );
Insert into test (Article_ID, Product_ID, Name, Description, Type, Category, Color, Price, Commission, Currency, URL_Product, URL_Picture__big_ ) values ( 16211582, 1001098367, 'Team Trash Talk -  Jumpshot', 'Exclusive to Morel Tees - Team Trash Talk deadly jump shot This is a must have for all those that spend their time in pick up games.  Let everyone else know that the court is now yours.', 'Men''s T-Shirt', 'T-Shirts', 'white', 20, 2, 'USD', 'http://MorelTees.spreadshirt.com/team-trash-talk-jumpshot-A16211582', 'http://image.spreadshirtmedia.com/image-server/v1/products/1001098367/views/2,width=190,height=190.png' );
```

Actual error is - Query completed with errors

Comment: can't you insert the 100,000 rows in one `insert` command?

Comment: I fail to see how.  None of the data is in the database at all.  If it was I could use an Insert into (select ...) but this script is to be used to populate the data into the test table.

Comment: Out of scope but, how you came up with an insert script of over 100.000 rows?

Comment: "throws an error". Can you please post the actual error thrown?

Comment: What is the error?  Perhaps your code is violating a unique constraint or something similar.

Comment: you are probably running out of log space -- put a few commits in there and see if it works better.

Comment: I built a tool to read the data and then write the insert statements based off of the spreadsheet given. I kept receiving spreadsheets that I needed to upload to the database to run test against prior to uploading to production. None of the spreadsheets were ever just ready to upload and could take hours or days to correct data in the spreadsheet just so that it would work through the import process.  So my tool escapes and sterilizes the data for insert.  It also take the column headings as the column names.  All I have to do is add a row of data types for each column.

Comment: You are aware that basic INSERT INTO syntax allows multiple rows with one statement?

Comment: So maybe with some effort you could make your tool to insert the data to database instead of produce the inserts. Just a thought.

Comment: @TomTom no I am not.  How is that done?

Comment: I would add that ability if not for the fact that my clients sys admin does not  want another connection to the database. States that more connections slow the database down and that using management studio is enough since it is what he uses and what the developer prior to me used and it was "good enough".

Comment: @MarkHart Head over to the documentation and read the syntax for insert into.

Comment: So good luck with clients like those. I understood that you want to run the script first on a staging database, do your checks and if all is ok then run it to production database. My guess is that maybe there is a size limitation on log file. Please check just in case.

Comment: @TomTom thanks I looked it up but I see that all the cool stuff is for 2008 or later.  This server is 2005.  Just as well at least these insert statements should work no matter the edition.

Comment: Oh my, well... Not that you tag that, right? Not sure what to say - I generally do not really deal with systems so ancient they are out of main support and on the intensive care station (extended support). Not a lot you can do then on that system - that syntax change WAS 2008. You could try a bulk copy, but then - not sure that ancient syntax has the API for that. Bulk Load works magic in terms of loading 100k rows in seconds.

Comment: I fail to see where a connection (SSMS or something else) would make a difference, one connection is one connection.  Connections in and of themselves are not often the issue for performance unless you run out of them.  I would bet I could open, run and close a connection in a C# program faster than you could do it manually in SSMS though.

Comment: Hey no disagreement here.  The sys admin is a jerk and just likes to blame the programmers.  If one system has issues and the other 90 are running fine, in his eyes it is a programming issue because we made changes.  Never mind that XP is the OS and their are no controls to keep users from downloading anything. If we make any changes then we caused everything. Client wants more features but sys admin will no upgrade their systems to handle the extra resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some troubleshooting and was able to insert up to 25,000 with out issue and then it started doing weird things.  Most of my errors at that point in management studio were out of memory errors.  I am going to toss this up to limits based on hardware and just adjust to running smaller number of insert statements.

Thanks all.